# generate .lib and .dll file from .Net C# code

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to import a .dll file in C++ code to be able to use all the methods and parameters inside the DLL. But I did not manage this so far, as I have no .lib file. It seems this is needed, and not just the .dll
So I managed to get the complete project that generates the .dll. It is a C# project that compiles using scriptcs and mono.
I run makefile from a Cygwin window on Windows10.
The DNL.dll and DNL_MATLAB.dll files get generated fine, but no trace of the lib file.
I have no clue how to generate the .lib file.
Can anyone help me ?

I tried to generate the .lib from the .dll file with dumpbin, but it completely fails.
I attach the makefile that generates the two .dll files, to show what it does.
As mentioned above, it does generate a DNL.dll and a DNL_MATLAB.dllfile, but no .lib file
I looked on the web a lot but could not found an answer to this question.

```
.PHONY: clean generate ./bin/Release/DNL.dll

all: clean generate  ./bin/Release/DBL.dll ./bin/Release/DNL_MATLAB.dll

generate:  
    @cd doc; doxygen Doxyfile_DNL
    @rm -rf ./bin/data/xml
    @cd data && doxygen val_NET_doxygen_conf
    @mkdir -p ./var
    @rm -rf ./var/*
    scriptcs ./build/scripts/GenerateAPI.csx -- release/v5.1.0/ Release 0 val Single

./bin/bin/Release/DNL.dll: 
    mkdir -p ./bin/Release
    mkdir -p ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @rm -f ./src/Source_GENERAL/*.cs
    @cp -f ./src/auto*.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/Api.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/ErrorCodes.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/Host.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/IController.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/Logger.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/HelperFunctions.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/Spi.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    @cp -f ./src/UUTBase.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    mcs ./src/Source_GENERAL/*.cs ./src/Controllers/*.cs -t:library -out:./bin/Release/DNL.dll -r:System.Net.Http -sdk:4.6.1
    @rm -f ./src/Source_GENERAL/*
    @rm -r ./src/Source_GENERAL

./bin/Release/DNL_MATLABl.dll: 
    mkdir -p ./bin/Release
    mkdir -p ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @rm -f ./src/Source_MATLAB/*.cs
    @cp -f ./src/mat*.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/Api.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/ErrorCodes.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/Host.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/IController.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/Logger.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/Spi.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/HelperFunctions.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @cp -f ./src/UUTBase.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    mcs ./src/Source_MATLAB/*.cs ./src/Controllers/*.cs -t:library -out:./bin/Release/DNL_MATLAB.dll -r:System.Net.Http -sdk:4.6.1
    @rm -f ./src/Source_MATLAB/*.cs
    @rm -r ./src/Source_MATLAB

./bin/Debug/DNL.dll:
    mkdir -p ./bin/Release
    @cp -f ./src/*.cs ./src/Source_GENERAL
    $(CC) ./src/Source_GENERAL/*.cs ./src/Controllers/*.cs -t:library -debug -out:$(BINDIR)/$(CONFIG)/ DNL.dll -r:System.Net.Http -sdk:4.6.1
    @rm -f ./src/Source_GENERAL/*.cs

./bin/Debug/DNL_MATLAB.dll:
    mkdir -p ./bin/Release
    @cp -f ./src/*.cs ./src/Source_MATLAB
    mcs ./src/Source_MATLAB/*.cs ./src/Controllers/*.cs -t:library -debug -out:./bin/Release/DNL_MATLAB.dll -r:System.Net.Http -sdk:4.6.1
    @rm -f ./src/Source_MATLAB/*.cs

clean:
    @rm -rf doc/out/html
    @rm -rf doc/out/latex
    @rm -f ./src/auto*
    @rm -f ./src/mat*
    #@rm -rf ./bin/*
    @rm -rf ./src/Source_MATLAB
    @rm -rf ./src/Source_GENERAL

run: build
    @mono ./bin/app.exe

test: ./bin/Release/DNL.dll
    @rm -rf ./bin/Release/logs
    python3 ./test/python_test.py ./bin/Release/DNL.dll

hwtest: ./bin/Release/DNL.dll
    @rm -rf ./bin/Release/logs
    python3 ./test/python_hw_test.py ./bin/Release/DNL.dll
```

The folder Source_GENERAL contains many .cs files, I show one (part of a file) here for refence

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace DNL
{
        public class _ADC12 : _module
    {
        static internal UInt32 myModuleAddress = 0x7;
        public class _PON : _register
        {
            static internal UInt32 myAddress = (myModuleAddress << 12) | 0x0;
            public _PON(_UUTBase _owner) : base(_owner, myAddress) {}
            public _spi F_PonLaunch {get => _owner.SpiProvider(myAddress, "PonLaunch");}
            public _spi F_Reserved0 {get => _owner.SpiProvider(myAddress, "Reserved0");}

        }
        public _PON R_PON { get { return new _PON(_owner); } }

        public class _CALIBRATION_STATUS : _register
        {
            static internal UInt32 myAddress = (myModuleAddress << 12) | 0x4;
            public _CALIBRATION_STATUS(_UUTBase _owner) : base(_owner, myAddress) {}
            public _spi F_CalibrationBusy {get => _owner.SpiProvider(myAddress, "CalibrationBusy");}
            public _spi F_CalibrationLaunchedOkay {get => _owner.SpiProvider(myAddress, "CalibrationLaunchedOkay");}
            public _spi F_Reserved0 {get => _owner.SpiProvider(myAddress, "Reserved0");}

        }
```

Comment: _"**I want to import a .dll** file in C++ code to be able to use all the methods and parameters inside the DLL. But I did not manage this so far, **as I have no .lib file**"_ - from a pure native code point of view, you don't need a **.LIB** file in order to use a **.DLL**.  You can just `LoadModule` it at runtime and pull out the exports.  Now, as for .NET you **can't** as there are no `EXPORT`s by default.  .NET DLLs are not regular DLLs that say native user code or tools like Dependency Viewer will find useful.

Comment: Maybe c++/CLI would be more to your liking?

Comment: Thanks MickyD. Do you mean using LoadModule and then GetProcAddress to import the .dll in C++ ? I want to avoid that, because I have litterally hundreds, if not thousands methods and parameters to import, that is huge. I need something that imports the complete content of the .dll, like clr does in python.
My C++ code is already in C++/CLI, but without the .lib, I am stuck.
Can you direct me to how the export would work on the C# .Net code ? Would that allow generating the .lib file ?

Comment: I'm saying 1) you don't need a lib file to use a DLL you can just use LoadModule 2) .NET does not produce a lib file anyway 3) All of this is academic because .NET has no EXPORTs for you to use regardless of whether you use LoadModule or a .LIB (which .NET won't produce anyway)

Comment: Is there a way then to load the complete content of the dll file (all its classes and enums) in one go into the C++ project ? Any example on the web ?